# Firefox - Windows High Contrast Mode Disabled Button Color Issue

Tags: css, firefox, high-contrast

I have a requirement to make the disabled material button border and color as green color in windows high contrast mode. The css changes are working fine with chrome, but facing some issue with firefox. Whatever the color applied to border, it is automatically turning to white only. Is there any way we can override the color to green for firefox?

```
    /*For chrome, working as expected */
    @media (forced-colors: active) {
    material-button[disabled] {
      forced-color-adjust: none;
      border: 1px solid GrayText;
    }
  }

  /* For Firefox, not working */
  @media (prefers-contrast: more) {
    material-button[disabled] {
      border: 1px solid GrayText;
    }
  }
```

Can someone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2021, NO major browsers support the `prefers-contrast` media feature, so your second media query won't work. It's a red herring in any case, because Windows High Contrast mode doesn't necessarily imply any particular contrast level. The user can pick *any* colours they want, and some users employ the Windows High Contrast feature to create *low* contrast colour palettes.

Firefox supports the `forced-colors` media feature (since version 89), but has not yet implemented the `forced-color-adjust` property. However the `forced-color-adjust` property isn't required if you just want to specify a system colour keyword such as `GrayText`. Your first media query and border colour should work in Firefox.

Note that Firefox's adherence to system colours is optional. It's based on a user preference at *Preferences > General > Colors > Use system colors*. If this option is checked, then Firefox will use the colours specified in Windows' High Contrast OS settings. Otherwise, it will use colours from Firefox's browser settings.